# Django Localization: How do we properly translate a string if there are links embedded?

Tags: django, django-templates, localization, internationalization

How do we properly add translation functionality to strings **without** breaking them into smaller parts? I would like to make it easier for translators to be able to translate strings.

For example, please consider the following:

```
<p>By clicking on "register", you agree to our <a href="{% url 'terms' %}">terms of service</a>, <a href="{% url 'privacy' %}">privacy policy</a> and <a href="{% url 'forum_guidelines' %}">forum guidelines</a></p>
```

If we use trans tags `{% trans "" %}`, this would have to be broken up into 6 individual parts, which would make it very difficult to localize into other languages:

```
1) {% trans "By clicking on "register", you agree to our" %}
2) {% trans "terms of service" %} 
3) {% trans "," %} 
4) {% trans "privacy policy" %}
5) {% trans "and" %}
6) {% trans "forum guidelines" %}
```

I've read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/), but I still do not understand how to approach this issue. I am hoping you guys know how to do this or have a properly solution for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`blocktrans`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag):

```
{% url 'terms' as terms_url %}
{% url 'privacy_url' as privacy_url %}
{% url 'forum_guidelines' as forum_guidelines_url %}

<p>
    {% blocktrans trimmed %}
        By clicking on "register", you agree to our 
        <a href="{{ terms_url }}">terms of service</a>, 
        <a href="{{ privacy_url }}">privacy policy</a> and 
        <a href="{{ forum_guidelines_url }}">forum guidelines</a>
    {% endblocktrans %}
</p>
```

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "not show the url"? The example would work nicely with all major tools that translators are using.